# An object property is not being defined, but it sometimes is defined when I refresh the page or later in the code

Tags: javascript, windows

Hey there I have this piece of code that gets the users geolocation and stores that in a location property of a Data class, simple enough.

When I use the default constructor for this function I want it to call the function

`_initLocation()`

To define the _location property.

This is the code for the object:

```
  constructor(){
    this._initLocation();
    this._dataStore = new Map();
  }
  
  _initLocation(){
    if(navigator.geolocation){
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position) => {
      const { latitude, longitude } = position.coords;
      this._location = new Array(latitude, longitude);

      }, () => alert('location not found'))
    }
  }

  get location(){
    return this._location;
  }

  get dataStore(){
    return this._dataStore;
  }

  icon = L.icon({
    iconUrl: 'icon.png',
    
    iconSize: [100, 100],
    iconAnchor: [50, 100],
    popupAnchor: [0, -100],
  });

}
```

When I use this same code outside of the Object, it works perfectly fine, but whenever I try to use console.log on the newly created object I get:

```
Object { icon: {…}, _dataStore: Map(0) }
​
_dataStore: Map(0)
​
icon: Object { options: {…}, _initHooksCalled: true }
​
<prototype>: Object { … }
```

So there is no location property on this object, but later on if I console.log the object that property will later exist. It also sometimes appears on refresh. It's ruining code later in the project because that location data is required but undefined. It's clear I need some delay or lag? I've tried DOMContentLoaded. But I'm also uncertain as to why the alert popup isn't showing if it can't get the current location?

Also frustratingly when I console.log the location value in the `_initLocation()` function I get the correct data, but if I console.log the `_location` property I get 'undefined'??

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

### Edit, here is how I'm using that object:

I instantiate the object then I used it in an object named Renderer, by assigning it to _maptyData property. I then use that property in these functions:

```
  createMap(){
    this.map = L.map('map')
    .setView(this.maptyData.location, 13);

    L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.fr/hot/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
      attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'})
      .addTo(this.map);
  }
  
  createMarker(atLocation = maptyData.location){
    if(atLocation === maptyData.location) {
      console.log(maptyData._location);
      this._locMarker = L.marker(atLocation, {icon: maptyData.icon})
      .addTo(this.map)
      .bindPopup('Your current location')
      .openPopup();
      console.log(this._locMarker);
    } else {
      this.currentMarker = L.marker(atLocation, {icon: maptyData.icon})
      .addTo(this.map)
      .bindPopup('Please enter event information!')
      .openPopup();
      return this.currentMarker;
    }
```

Comment: Please show how you use this class

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this problem, I'm new to javascript and later realised the problem is because the code needs to be async, I learnt about promises and implemented them to fix this.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).